# applying function to each group using dplyr and return specified dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I used group_map for the first time and think I do it correctly. This is my code:

```
library(REAT)

df <- data.frame(value = c(1,1,1, 1,0.5,0.1, 0,0,0,1), group = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,3))

haves <- df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    group_map(~gini(.x$value, coefnorm = TRUE))
```

The thing is that haves is a list rather than a data frame. What would I have to do to obtain this df

```
wants <- data.frame(group = c(1,2,3), gini = c(0,0.5625,1))

group gini
1   0.0000
2   0.5625
3   1.0000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::summarize`:

```r
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarize(gini = gini(value, coefnorm = TRUE))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   group  gini
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 0    
#> 2     2 0.562
#> 3     3 1
```

Comment: I must be stupid as I have not thought about this. gini is basically a function like median, n_distinct etc. ....

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, `group_map` always produces a list. `group_modify` is an alternative that produces a tibble if the function does, but `gini` just outputs a vector.  So, you could do something like this...

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify(~tibble(gini = gini(.x$value, coefnorm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   group [3]
  group  gini
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 0    
2     2 0.562
3     3 1
```

Comment: Thanks - appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(gini = gini(value, coefnorm = TRUE)), group]
```

---

For grouped datasets, we can specify `.data` if in case we don't want to use column names unquoted

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   summarize(gini = gini(.data$value, coefnorm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks. Hardly use data.tables but they are more scalable AFAIK?